# Not able to fetch data from Angular 8 service

Tags: javascript, angular

Method in component -

```
        login(loginForm: NgForm) {
          debugger;
          let verifyUser;
          this.aService.verifyUser(loginForm.value.userName).subscribe(
         (data) => {verifyUser = data; },
         error => {console.warn(error); },
         () => {console.log("Success");}
      );
     if (verifyUser !== 1) {
      this.userNotFound = true;
    } else {
      sessionStorage.setItem('loginedUser', loginForm.value.userName);
      console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('loginedUser'));
    }
```

service -

```
public verifyUser(user: string) {
    debugger
    let returnValue;
    const url = 'https://localhost:44308/api/auth/verifyUserName?username=' + user;
    returnValue = this.http.get(url).pipe(
      tap(
        data => console.log('data' + data),
        error => console.error(error)
      )
    );
    return returnValue;
  }
```

I'm getting logged data in console in tap method in service but not able use it in component where I subscribe it. Even it is logging success message in component.

Comment: Can you put the console inside component, and share the result

(data) => {
   console.log(data);
   verifyUser = data;
},

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the asynchronous nature of this is returning undefined?

Change to:

```
public verifyUser(user: string) {
debugger
const url = 'https://localhost:44308/api/auth/verifyUserName?username=' + user;
return this.http.get(url).pipe(
  tap(
    data => console.log('data' + data),
    error => console.error(error)
  )
);
```

}

Comment: Still doesn't work. I'm able to log data from tap but when I subscribe it in component I'm getting it as undefined. Am I missing something?

Comment: What does the data in the console.log look like?

Comment: I'll get 1 or -1 based on user.

Answer (score 0):

```
public verifyUser(user: string) {
debugger
const url = 'https://localhost:44308/api/auth/verifyUserName?username=' + user;
return this.http.get<any>(url).pipe(
  tap(
    data => console.log('data' + data),
    error => console.error(error)
  )
);
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.